# How to use a custom pre-trained language model in LangChain

Tags: python, tensorflow, langchain

I have trained a model by means of Keras and Tensorflow in python. A little GPT model trained on a large structured Pdf file.

I would like ti use this model with LangChain to build a Question/Answer application.

Is It possibile to use such a model in LangChain?

Answer (score 0):

I’m a noob in this area but it is possible with [langchain docs](https://js.langchain.com/docs/get_started). There can you find the way. But you also have to train your AI to recognise and understand sentences and questions.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Viiiinie How may I train the gpt model to answer a question?